# CKeditor hide overflow-x in textarea

Tags: javascript, css, coldfusion, ckeditor, ckeditor5

[image]My problem is that i cant hide this overflow-x in the Textarea.

**Here u can see what I mean:**
[image: Here u can see what I mean]

I've tried it with this code the overflow is still there. I dont know how can I hide it that the textarea is normal again.

```js
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#toolbar1' ),{
          toolbar: ['heading','|','bold','italic','|','link','bulletedList','numberedList','|','undo','redo']})
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#toolbar2' ),{
          toolbar: ['heading','|','bold','italic','|','link','bulletedList','numberedList','|','undo','redo']})
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#toolbar3' ),{
          toolbar: ['heading','|','bold','italic','|','link','bulletedList','numberedList','|','undo','redo']})
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#toolbar4' ),{
          toolbar: ['heading','|','bold','italic','|','link','bulletedList','numberedList','|','undo','redo']})
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/28.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <style>
      #toolbar1{
          overflow:hidden !important;
      }
    </style>
  
<cfform action="" method="post">
  <cfoutput>
    <cfinput name="access" type="hidden" value="save">
    <cfinput name="kprec" type="hidden" value="#KPProjekt.KPID#">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12" style="padding:10px"><nobr>DE:<cftextarea id="toolbar1" name="TextDE">#KPProjekt.KPTextDE#</cftextarea></nobr></div>
      <div class="col-12" style="padding:10px"><nobr>FR:<cftextarea id="toolbar2" class="form-control" name="TextFR">#KPProjekt.KPTextFR#</cftextarea></nobr></div>
      <div class="col-12" style="padding:12px"><nobr>&nbsp;IT:<cftextarea id="toolbar3" class="form-control" name="TextIT">#KPProjekt.KPTextIT#</cftextarea></nobr></div>
      <div class="col-12" style="padding:7px"><nobr>EN:<cftextarea id="toolbar4" class="form-control" name="TextEN">#KPProjekt.KPTextEN#</cftextarea></nobr></div><br>
      </div>
   <cfinput name="save" value="speichern" type="submit">
   <div>&nbsp;</div>
 </cfoutput>
 </cfform>
```

Comment: Looks to me that your CSS is correct and should work properly.  Can you post an image of what you see when you do an inspect element on `#toolbar1`?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: I don't see the overflow property in your screen shot.

Comment: I could solve the problem. Its because of the <nobr> tag. If u remove the tag there's no need for the CSS style in the head tag. The nobr tag doesnt allowe you to breack any kind of Text.